# Why does ELU get a special background for Time Travel mode?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, april-fools, time-travel-mode

[ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/492016/when-be-it-is-at-the-beginning-of-a-sentence-what-kind-of-structure-do-you-ca) seems to get a textured background displayed right behind text elements:

[image]

(Or rather, it's the same background as on all the sites, but other sites that I've looked at have a plain color behind text.)

I wonder why, and whether there are any other sites where Time Travel Mode looks like this. (Edit: questions on https://judaism.stackexchange.com/ also look like this to me.) Is it a bug, either with the site or with my browser? Even taking into account that it's an April Fools' mode, I'm not sure that it's intentional for it to be so much harder to read posts on ELU or Mi Yodeya vs. on Stack Oveflow or on beta sites.

Comment: Thanks for the report. We're looking into it. It shouldn't be behaving this way. We've temporarily disabled the theme entirely on these two sites until we can figure out what was causing this. If you notice other sites that are having this issue, please let us know!

Comment: What is more remarkable about this is the further question it raises how in the newly unified and cross-site-standardized design this *could even happen*, given that easy cross-site deployment of design changes was the major selling point of the theme migration.

Comment: @ChristianRau It's supposed to reduce it as much as possible. There are still going to be little things that cause these problems... for example, look at the header bar on [rpg.se]. The opacity in the image layer makes the tiled background visible whereas on M&TV and here it's not visible behind the banner at all. But, knowing that this happened, we can also look at those two sites and see what's different and why this might have happened and see if it's possible to change the behavior in the future. :)

Comment: @Catija Granted. If I had to guess, it might be related to their usage of serifed fonts in more than the usual places, since I remember these two sites being a primary catalyst for adjustments in that direction.

Comment: I'm not seeing this on either ELU or MY. Maybe it's a loading issue, where the background loads but the solid colors don't? Not sure why it would only affect some users, on some sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For what it's worth, this was fixed:

[image: Fixed screenshot]

You can test it by using the [script the goes back in time to when the Time Machine was active](https://stackapps.com/questions/8287/2019-april-fools-day-retro-theme). You can also see the code that fixed the problem:

```
if ($("#content").css('backgroundColor') === 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' && $("body").css('backgroundColor') !== 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)') {
    $("#content").css('backgroundColor', $("body").css('backgroundColor'));
}
```

In essence, the `#content` background color on some sites is transparent, which allowed the body background image to be displayed. After the fix, the `#content` background color was set to the site's body background color if it wasn't also transparent.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Not just page backgrounds.  Allow me to present a header with...issues:

[image: screenshot from Workplace, with tiled background instead of page banner]

Comment: This is actually a different thing. The report here's already fixed. This is similar to what I mentioned in a comment about RPG and it's not quite by design but it's appropriate for the theme so we weren't planning to fix it.